# Private network with 2 servers on scaleway

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, private-blockchain

first of all thank you for the great discussions and solution that I've found here.

I'm trying to create a private ethereum network to which I want to access with 2 different servers.

I am able to create the network with and ID say 1234 and then attach to it another instance of geth (using `geth --dev attach`). So with 2 accounts on the same machine I am able to mine, transfer ether between the two and also develop smart contracts (like the greeter example) and invoke the greet() function on the other instance after `set var greeter = eth.contract(ABI).at('ADDRESS')`.

Now I want to connect to this network from another server to which I access with ssh at a certain IP. Also here geth is working. 
I've defined the same *genesis.json* file and then I have `geth init genesis.json`.

I've also defined a *static-nodes.json* file so to connect to the first server. This is where things are not working.

If from within the js console I invoke something like:

```
admin.addPeer("enode://9a5fe07ba826bdfc266137c4d2668c54dd659fe289858198d869ef7b9828461bd7c247834cf233d75b44a45f873d69edda05b9c9423f0c22cae451bf0df92c5c@first.server.ip.scaleway:30303?discport=0")
```

then I see something like this:

```
I1020 14:46:13.094602 eth/downloader/downloader.go:326] Block synchronisation started
I1020 14:46:13.256432 eth/downloader/queue.go:885] Peer 9a5fe0xxxxxxxxxx: header #114 [80xxxxxx] broke chain ancestry
```

Due to the fact that there is a block #114, I think the first server is able to send information about the chain with ID 1234, but the synchronisation is not possible. If I start mining on the second server, it starts from block #0.

Sorry for the lenght of the explanation but in this way I think I've written everything. I don't know if the problem is due to geth or my server on scaleway.

Thank you again for all your help :)

Comment: which version are you using : geth version

Comment: Are you sure the genesis blocks are the same? I'd recommend against using the `--dev` flag; it sets a lot of different options, some of which may be overriding things that you've specified.

Comment: If you have the `static-nodes.json` file, you need not use the `addPeer()` function to connect the nodes. Check the output of `admin.peers` to see if the connections was successful.

Comment: @BadrBellaj I've installed it 2 day ago through the official repository, so it's the latest geth

Comment: @TjadenHess I use the `--dev` option only within the same server, and it works correctly. The problems arises when I use different servers, where I use the classic geth --networkid syntax. I am sure the genesis file is the same because I've checked the hash within the console and they are the same.
It's possible to use attach command also from different servers?

Comment: @variable The problem is that the `static-nodes.json` seems not working. When I run `admin.peers` I have not peers between the []. Sometimes the peer is added after `addPeer()`, but then I get the error about broke chain anchestry and then get disconnected.

Comment: Could you post the full command you're using for each node?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use the attach command from a different server if you use the `--rpc` flag. Then you just do `geth attach http://MyIP:8545`

Comment: I'll try to attach from the other server asap (tonight) and I'll let you know :)